# Show/hide and change icon with jQuery

Tags: jquery

OK, I have couple of elements, when clicked they need to have an icon changed and show a corresponding hidden element. I feel like I'm quite close but still something is missing and the code works only partially:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".fList").hide();
$(".features").click(function() {
    var that = this;
    var pid  = $(this).attr("id")+"C";
    $(".fList:visible").slideUp();
    $(".features .ui-icon-triangle-1-s").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e");
    $("#"+pid).slideDown(function(){
        $("span.ui-icon-triangle-1-e", that).removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="f1" class="features">
    <span class="uico ui-icon-triangle-1-e icoSpan"></span>Features
  </td>
  <td id="f2" class="features">
    <span class="uico ui-icon-triangle-1-e icoSpan"></span>Features
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="f1C" class="fList">
111111
</div>  

<div id="f2C" class="fList">
22222
</div>
```

What am I missing? I need to be able to close all or open only one area...

Comment: What works and what dose not work?

Comment: @Andersson Everything works properly initially, but once the section is shown I can't seem to be able to close. I think I need to integrate toggle somehow.

Comment: Seems to work fine. Check http://jsfiddle.net/43WRp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two parts of the code strike me as problematic:

```
$(".fList:visible").slideUp();
```

If an `.fList` element is not visible, sliding up won't do anything, so you might want to test with simply:

```
  $(".fList").slideUp();
```

Also I think that in order to use slideDown(), that element must be previously "slided up" or display: none... but I'm not 100% sure, so that might cause problems when you try and show an element via slideDown().

Next I'm confused why the variable `that` is included in the following line:

```
$("span.ui-icon-triangle-1-e", that)
```

the variable `that` refers to the clicked element, which doesn't seem to have any of the classes you're adding or removing-- are you sure you want to be altering it's class?

---

If you want to have two different behaviors: 1) For clicking a div.feature that's been selected, to *close* another element and 2) for clicking a div.feature that *has not* been selected in order to *open* another element. Maybe something like this:

```
var $features = $('.features');
$features.click(function() {
    var that = this
        pid  = that.attr("id")+"C";

    if(that.hasClass('current')) {
        $features.removeClass('current');
        $("#"+pid).slideUp(500, function(){
            // Change icons etc..
        });
    } else {
        $features.removeClass('current');
        that.addClass('current');
        $(".fList").slideUp();
        $(".features .ui-icon-triangle-1-s").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e");
        $("#"+pid).slideDown(function(){
            $("span.ui-icon-triangle-1-e", that).removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: $("span.ui-icon-triangle-1-e", that) only changes the style in the elements that has been clicked. Without "that" both icons change style when just one is clicked.

Comment: And removing the :visible selector didn't help?

Comment: No, I think I need to add toggle somewhere to allow closing too is the element that opened an hidden div is clicked again.

Comment: I think toggle can get messy when dealing with elements spread across multiple parents (as opposed to clicking to hide or show a single or a couple elements with the same parent). I would add a "current" class to the clicked .feature div... see answer for more